# RegEx Question on Linux - Sorting Date

Tags: regular-expression

It is possible to ignore some of the fields in an regex expression. The issue is that I have an output of a sorted files from an FTP server. The problem is that FTP does not list the year from the files that are 6 months or newer. So for example if I want to sort this `020319` and `100518` and I want to list the latest by date it will sort first `100518`, and that's not good.

FTP_FILES_LIST is a file with a bunch of files from an "ls" command from an FTP Site. I use "grep" to get only the files I'm interested in.

```
A="AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_"

more FTP_FILES_LIST | grep "$A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt" | sort -k 9

-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34037013 Jan 17 00:45 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_011719.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34036101 Jan 18 11:13 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_011819.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34036564 Jan 25 01:09 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_012519.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34041306 Feb 03 21:42 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_020319.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34099207 Feb 08 03:15 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_020819.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34099827 Feb 11 02:55 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_021119.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34010091 Oct 05 00:42 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_100518.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34025780 Nov 26 02:55 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_112618.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34037370 Dec 19 22:10 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_121918.txt
```

Using the "sed" doesn't sort as it should not sort as it should be. Here is the output:

```
more FTP_FILES_LIST | grep $A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | sed -E 's/^(..)(..)(..)/\3\1\2/' | sort | sed -E 's/^(..)(..)(..)/\2\3\1/'

-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34010091 Oct 05 00:42 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_100518.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34025780 Nov 26 02:55 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_112618.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34036101 Jan 18 11:13 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_011819.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34036564 Jan 25 01:09 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_012519.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34037013 Jan 17 00:45 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_011719.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34037370 Dec 19 22:10 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_121918.txt -> Wrong sort!
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34041306 Feb 03 21:42 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_020319.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34099207 Feb 08 03:15 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_020819.txt
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34099827 Feb 11 02:55 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_021119.txt
```

It is possible to group the dates in pairs with sed and/or regex? I have six [0-9]; one per each date digit. What about
if its possibe to us regex or sed to sort those in pairs? like for example 100518; to sort 10 then 05 then 18.

Using `more FTP_FILES_LIST | grep "$A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][9].txt" | sort -k 9` is a workaround but I'm losing all files from 2018. I added a picture of the output because the format changes here!
[image]

Comment: None of your output lists matches the `grep` commands you're using. (For example, using the first `grep` in your question against the set of files you've shown returns no results.) Please go back and [edit] your question so that they match.

Comment: It looks to me like you just want to sort by the 5th *character* of the 1st (only) field on i.e. `sort -k1.5` - I don't see how regular expressions need to be involved here at all

Comment: your use of -k9 makes it sound like you're parsing the output of an ftp `ls` command; is that true?

Comment: Post updated; please now its more understandable and can received a good answer. Thanks to all

Comment: @JavierGonzalez, I've updated my answer given the actual filenames; give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples I assume the file names are in the format `MMDDYY.txt` where `MM` is month, `DD` is day and `YY` is year.

You could rearrange the characters for sorting using `sed`

```
sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)/\2\1/'| sort | sed 's/\(..\)\(....\)/\2\1/'
```

or if your `sed` supports option `-E` for extended regular expressions

```
sed -E 's/(....)(..)/\2\1/'| sort | sed -E 's/(..)(....)/\2\1/'
```

The first `sed` will exchange the first group of 4 characters (`MMDD`) and the second group of 2 characters (`YY`). Whatever may follow (`.txt`) will be unchanged. This will change `100518.txt` to `181005.txt` etc. After sorting the characters are exchanged back.

This script assumes the list of filenames is already filtered to contain only names of the correct format. Otherwise the match patterns should be more complicated to match only 6 numbers followed by `.txt`.

`sort` without option will put the highest date last, use `sort -r` to reverse the order

Comment: If you `sed -E` then you don't need to escape the `()`

Comment: `ls *.txt | sed -E 's/^(..)(..)(..)/\3\1\2/' | sort | sed -E 's/^(..)(..)(..)/\2\3\1/'`

Comment: @bu5hman You are right, the pattern for `.txt` can be left out. I think the anchor `^` is not necessary because a series of grouped `.` will match anything from the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already assuming that the timestamps are in field 9, then you can tell `sort` to pick apart the three date fields:

```
sort -k9.24,9.25n -k9.20,9.21n -k9.22,9.23n FTP_FILES_LIST
```

Here's a sample run over your sample input using GNU sort's `--debug` option; you can see the series of dashed lines indicating the sort keys that `sort` used in succession to determine the ordering:

```
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34010091 Oct 05 00:42 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_100518.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34025780 Nov 26 02:55 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_112618.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34037370 Dec 19 22:10 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_121918.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34037013 Jan 17 00:45 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_011719.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34036101 Jan 18 11:13 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_011819.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34036564 Jan 25 01:09 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_012519.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34041306 Feb 03 21:42 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_020319.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34099207 Feb 08 03:15 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_020819.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
-r-xr-xr-x    1 14       2000     34099827 Feb 11 02:55 AT_20_10_REL_ARCA_021119.txt
                                                                              __
                                                                          __
                                                                            __
____________________________________________________________________________________
```

Doing the sorting this way is fragile in that it relies on the filenames to start in the 9th whitespace-delimited field. An alternative would be to use some reliance on the filename pattern itself, perhaps the appearance of the timestamp in the 6th underscore-delimited:

```
sort -t_ -k6.5,6.6n -k6.1,6.2n -k6.3n,6.4n FTP_FILES_LIST
```

Comment: Yes jeff. Its a single file with a list from all files from an ftp

Comment: Hi Jeff. I edited my post; maybe can help better to answer the question. Sadly the "sed" didnt sort as expected. Read my new updated post please. Maybe can help